# PartialView(); The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv, partial-views

So im a bit stuck.  I'm still learning all this stuff., but I had to add a csv parser to my application, which should display the results on the my alerts page.  If I do

```
return PartialView(model, pin, tDate, stat);
```

It will tell me pin, tDate and stat does not exist in the current context.  If I take them out, the app will run, but doesn't display the intended result.

I declared pin, tDate and stat in the UserADInfoModel.cs

here is the controller:

```
    public ActionResult _Alerts(UserADInfoModel model, List<string> groups)
    {
        DataRowCollection drColl = Core.GetAlerts(model);
        ViewBag.Alerts = drColl;

        var path = @"Exchange Migration data 10-25-17.csv";
        using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(path))
        {
            csvParser.CommentTokens = new string[] { "#" };
            csvParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
            csvParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

            // Skip the row with the column names
            csvParser.ReadLine(); 

            // Read the lines
            while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
                string pin = fields[0];
                string tDate = fields[2];
                string stat = fields[6];
            }
        }

        return PartialView(model, pin, tDate, stat);
    }
```

and here is the view

```
@if (@ViewBag.pin == Model.SAM)
    {
        <tr style="background-color : #ff3333; color: #ffffff">
            <td style="padding-left :10px; padding-right: 10px;padding-top:2px; padding-bottom: 2px">
                <p>Critical</p>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left :10px; padding-right: 10px;padding-top:2px; padding-bottom: 2px">
                <p>Exchange Migration</p>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left :10px; padding-right: 10px;padding-top:2px; padding-bottom: 2px">
                <p>Caller was set to migrate on (@ViewBag.tDate).  The status of the migration is (@ViewBag.stat). Please contact Hypercare</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    @foreach (var x in ViewBag.Alerts)
    {
        var uClass = (x["Weight"].Contains("Warning")) ? "#ff8c1a, " : (x["Weight"].Contains("Critical")) ? "#ff3333" : "";

        <tr @if (x["Weight"].Contains("Warning")) {
            @MvcHtmlString.Create("style=\"background-color: #ff8c1a\"")
        }
        else if(x["Weight"].Contains("Critical")){
            @MvcHtmlString.Create("style=\"background-color: #ff3333; color: #ffffff\"")

        }>
```

what am I doing wrong? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `pin`, `tDate` and `stat` inside the `while` scope.

Decide if you want to use model (recommended) or `ViewBag` to pass data:

```
public ActionResult _Alerts(UserADInfoModel model, List<string> groups)
{
    DataRowCollection drColl = Core.GetAlerts(model);
    ViewBag.Alerts = drColl;

    var path = @"Exchange Migration data 10-25-17.csv";
    using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(path))
    {
        // ...

        while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
            model.pin = fields[0];
            model.tDate = fields[2];
            model.stat = fields[6];
        }
    }

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

_Alerts.cshtml:

```
@model UserADInfoModel
@if (@Model.pin == Model.SAM)
// ...
// ... @Model.tDate ... @Model.stat ...
```

Comment: Did that and now I get return PartialView(model, pin, tDate, stat); No overload for method PartialView takes 4 arguments

Comment: thanks that worked!  No errors at least, its still not displaying the information, so I must have another issue somewhere else.

Comment: You might not have assigned `Model.SAM`.

Comment: figured it out, Model.SAM shows the correct pin the user enters, however the csv parse is not sending over the correct pin so its not matching.  Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Sure!  Is it just the check mark?  Thanks again, my boss was super excited